# kornshell -- using sed for replacement

Tags: regex, bash, unix, sed, ksh

If there is a text file that contains something like:

1 2 3 4 5 6

How do you replace everything before a certain string (4 for example) with a character such as a space?

1 2 3 4 5 6   (INPUT)

```
    4 5 6   (OUTPUT)
```

Comment: What should the output be if the line was: a) `1 2 3 5`, b) `1 2 4 5 4`, c) `1 2 47 3 4 5`, d) `1 2 34 5`? Can the string in question be longer than 1 character, e.g. `foo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ echo -e '1 2 3 4 5 6\n7 8 9 0 1 2'|
> sed 's/4/\n&/;T;h;s/^[^\n]*\n//;x;s/\n.*//;s/./ /g;G;s/\n//'
      4 5 6
7 8 9 0 1 2
$
```

Explained:

```
s/4/\n&/;T        # places "\n" marker before "4", quits otherwise
h;s/^[^\n]*\n//;x # puts "4 5 6" into hold space
s/\n.*//          # keeps only "1 2 3 "
s/./ /g           # replaces each char with space
G;s/\n//          # appends "4 5 6" from hold space
```

Answer (score 4):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/4/{:a;/^ *4/!s/[^ ]/ /;ta}' file
```

or:

```
sed 's/4/\n&/;T;h;s/[^\n]/ /g;G;s/\n.*\n//' file
```

or:

```
awk '/4/{while(!/^ *4/)sub(/[^ ]/," ")}1' file
```

or:

```
awk '/4/{sub(/4/,"\n&");h=$0;gsub(/[^\n]/," ");$0=$0 h;sub(/\n.*\n/,"")}1' file
```

Comment: I personally prefer simplicity of Your (2nd) solution over the performance of mine :) As for 1st solution (':a;s/\S(\s*4)/ \1/;ta') - it won't work properly on "1 2 3 4 5 4" input.

Comment: Thanks @Vlad. I've amended the first solution. Funny I had an inkling that it wasn't right but your test data filled in the logic gap. It makes sense to test the condition fails before trying to alter it!

Answer (score 3):

You're really getting into some arcane sed wizardry now. Keep it simple and just write it in awk using legible function names, variables, and understandable constructs:

```
$ cat file
1 2 3 4 5 6    
$ awk 'match($0,/4/){
    pre=substr($0,1,RSTART-1)
    gsub(/./," ",pre)
    print pre substr($0,RSTART)
}' file
      4 5 6
```

sed is an excellent tool for simple substitutions on a single line but for anything else just use awk. If you're using more than s, g, and p (with -n) sed language constructs then you've got the wrong tool for the job. Almost every other sed language construct became obsolete around 1976 once awk was invented.

If you come back in a year to enhance this script to do something different, e.g. print a count at the end of the line of now many chars were replaced with spaces, would you rather be faced with trying to understand and then modify this:

```
sed 's/\(4\)/\n\1/;Tq;h;s/^[^\n]*\n//;x;s/\n.*//;s/./ /g;G;s/\n//;:q'
```

or the above awk script? The tweak to do it in the awk script would simply be to add and print a variable (`cnt` below):

```
awk 'match($0,/4/){
    pre=substr($0,1,RSTART-1)
    cnt=gsub(/./," ",pre)
    print pre substr($0,RSTART), cnt
}' file
```

To make the sed script do it would, I expect, require 3 goats, a blood moon, and the batman symbol.

Comment: @anubhava Right. It's absolutely stunning to me how much effort people put into trying to force sed to solve the most trivial of problems. Someone who does this regularly told me they do it because they enjoy it in the same way they enjoy solving a difficult puzzle. That's nice for them but it leaves the people they're supposed to be trying to help with libraries of unintelligible gibberish in their bins!

Comment: It baffles me too after reading combo of those `a, ba, x, h H, G` sed commands :)

Comment: Excellent points made here. I fear they're going to fall on deaf ears though(in a few cases atleast). Some people simply are fixated with the sed hold buffer...

Comment: Awk indeed allows better readability, sed people just read s=substitute,h=hold as easy as awk people read "gsub"/etc. I used sed mostly due to "regex" tagged question (perl would've fit too, awk/python wouldn't show much regex usage). Besides - current awk snippet erases all input rows which don't have "4" in it...

Comment: There are no sed people and awk people any more than there are screwdriver people and hammer people, there's just people doing construction (software in this case) with a selection of available tools. I've been using sed for 30 years and I continue to use it more frequently than I use awk, almost daily as it's often the right tool for the simple substitution job at hand. It's a trivial tweak to make the awk script print lines without `4` in them as-is (assign $0 inside the existing action instead of printing there, then do a print outside it) if the OP wants that.

Comment: Oh, and wrt `awk/python wouldn't show much regex usage` - the awk solution doesn't do it all in an RE not because it doesn't have excellent support of REs but because there are better solutions and one that focused on doing it in an RE would be far more complex and unreadable for absolutely zero benefit.